# Different results of `summarize` and `group_by` with different months in time-series datasets

Tags: r, date, dplyr, time-series, lubridate

I have daily time-series data for more than 20 years. I want to extract the quantiles (0.1, 0.5, 0.9) by three months window for each year, which divided into JFM (Jan-Mar), FMA (Feb-Apr), ... and so on until OND (Oct-Dec). As a newbie in R, after so many days of research in the past two weeks, I finally found the method to do this. However, in the final step, I am stuck on this problem.

Actually, I am working using lists. But, for example, let's say we have this dataframe:

```
library(lubridate)
Date<-seq.Date(ymd(19700101),ymd(19721231),"day")
Q<-runif(ymd(19730101)-ymd(19700101),1,20)
df<-data.frame(Date,Q)
```

Now, we subset the df to obtain only specific three months (in this case JFM and FMA):

```
df.JFM<-df[months(df$Date) %in% month.name[1:3],] #cutting Jan-Mar
df.FMA<-df[months(df$Date) %in% month.name[2:4],] #cutting Feb-Apr
```

Then, to find the quantile of 50% for three-month series, I use this method:

```
library(dplyr)
df.JFM %>% group_by(Year=floor_date(Date, "3 months")) %>%
  summarize(Q=quantile(Q, 0.5, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Year           Q
  <date>     <dbl>
1 1970-01-01  8.83
2 1971-01-01  9.88
3 1972-01-01 11.3
```

No issue in the JFM set. Let's see for FMA set:

```
df.FMA %>% group_by(Year=floor_date(Date, "3 months")) %>%
  summarize(Q=quantile(Q, 0.5, na.rm=T))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Year           Q
  <date>     <dbl>
1 1970-01-01  8.75
2 1970-04-01 13.5 
3 1971-01-01  8.58
4 1971-04-01 13.2 
5 1972-01-01 10.2 
6 1972-04-01  8.29
```

Here, we found that the `floor_date` function round down the February dates to January dates of the same year. I expected that after I cut the data with February as the first element in the Date column, the `floor_date` would start from February. Apparently no. I also have tried with other three-month series and found that they give the same result as the FMA set. I also tried to change the index of the dataframe to become the same as the original index before the subset/cut, but no luck.

How to solve this problem?
Other methods for obtaining quantiles from a given period in a year (in the sense of my aim described at the beginning of the post) are also very welcomed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `floor_date`/`ceiling_date` performs rounding every 3 months always from the start of the year and not based on the dates in the data.

Here you may use `cut` instead which works as per your requirement.

```
library(dplyr)

df.JFM %>% 
  group_by(Year=cut(Date, "3 months")) %>%
  summarize(Q=quantile(Q, 0.5, na.rm=TRUE))

#  Year           Q
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 1970-01-01 11.0 
#2 1971-01-01 11.5 
#3 1972-01-01  9.57

df.FMA %>% 
  group_by(Year= cut(Date, '3 months')) %>%
  summarize(Q = quantile(Q, 0.5, na.rm=T))

#   Year        Q
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 1970-02-01 11.3 
#2 1971-02-01 10.5 
#3 1972-02-01  9.67
```